# Initramfs error during boot

Tags: root, init, initramfs

```
Boot from (hd0,0) ext3   238ac8ca-9576-443d-8e23-8dd836cd2683
Starting up ...
mount: mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/238ac8ca-9576-443d-8e23-8dd836cd2683 on /root
failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found.  Try passing init= bootarg.


BusyBox v1.15.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.15.3-1ubuntu5) built in shell (ash)

Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

Comment: Why a bounty, given the asking user is not seen on askubuntu from "Feb 12 at 16:04"?

Comment: But i need the answer for this, as i faced this issue few months back.

Comment: @karthick87: but are you the same user as @user10593? if not, why not open a new question, we cannot get anymore details from the asking user.

Comment: Lol i am not that  user. I thought that the existing user was regularaly using this site..

Answer (score 11):

Try the steps listed in this page:
[How to Fix an Ubuntu Error: "No init found. Try passing init= bootarg"](http://pinoy-computing-tips.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-fix-ubuntu-error-no-init-found.html)

Basically,

- Reboot with a live CD
- `sudo fdisk -l`

will get you the name of the disk then

- `sudo fsck /dev/sda`

Comment: for me it was sudo fsck /dev/sda1, but worked a champ, even though it couldn't mount. sweet!

Comment: What does fsck do? In general and in this case. That is also not explained in the source provided.

Comment: fsck = file system check

Comment: worked! For me,  the check has to be done on /dev/sda6 which is the system partition  in my case .     Answer "y" to all question during the check.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I just created ran the [Ubuntu Boot Repair disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and it fixed everything!

Answer (score 0):

Boot loader tries to boot from a partition which is not a correct linux root.
Would you please provide more information?How did it happen?

If it happened after an unexpected shutdown (just a guess) maybe file system check can help you: http://members.iinet.net.au/~herman546/p10.html#filesystem_check_on_an_ext3_filesystem

Comment: It did happen after a unexpected shutdown.  The link doesn't look like mine screen.