# Journal superblock is corrupt

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

Recently, when I booted my ubuntu partition, I recieved an Initramfs error. I followed the directions in this post:

[Initramfs error during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25695/initramfs-error-during-boot#)

However, when I ran the command:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdb1
```

(As a side note, my ubuntu partition is on sdb)
I recieved another error saying:

```
ext2fs_check_desc: Corrupt group descriptor: bad block for block bitmap
fsck.ext4: Group descriptors look bad... trying backup blocks...
Journal superblock has an unknown incompatible feature flag set.
Abort <y>?
```

I type no and the next thing says:

```
Journal superblock is corrupt
Fix<y>?
```

Next comes a series of y to fix this issue.

My question is this, is there a better method to fix a corrupt superblock? Or does this mean I need to reinstall ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me offer you a solution I found:

1. Reboot from a `live CD`
2. Find out which partition we are dealing with"

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   # but in your case its sdd1
   ```
3. Make sure its a superblock problem with:

   ```
   sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/xxx # in your case xxx => sdb
   ```
4. Check for your super block backups location:

   ```
   sudo mke2fs -n /dev/xxx

   # Results:
   Superblock backups stored on blocks:
   32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208
   ```
5. Restore superblock from backup with and repeat till its fixed:

   ```
   sudo e2fsck -b block_number /dev/xxx
   ```
6. If step `4` does not work repeat with next value in `step 3`

Source:

https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/

https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1245536.html