# How do I make whole system permanently read-only on Linux so even root can't have access?

Tags: boot, mount, read-only, overlayfs

After installing all the required drivers, I want my system to be in read-only mode. Even root can't change anything on the system. 
Usecases could, any virus should not affect the system or system will not crash easily.

I tried mount -r -o remount /, but root can get access to the system.

Comment: try this `mount -o remount,ro,noload /`

Comment: Outside of very special user cases, this is a silly idea. A virus could still read files from disk and have read/write access to RAM, which would easily crash the system. That said, if you are one of those cases, you might want to look at customizing a Live DVD.

Comment: @mikewhatever thanks, but can we make out system as live DVD ?
George it is not working.

Comment: An installed system without root write access would be non-functional unless it was a special setup such as the LiveUSB, which uses a RAM drive for the actual drive.  The system will have to write to the `root` filesystem as part of its operation.  You'd best look for a different method for securing your system.

Comment: @L.D.James yes you are right, but I am trying to learn Linux system. I want such kind of special system in which I will turn off most of the services and enable only network to send few desired files.

Comment: Or can we permanently do the normal system just like recovery mode?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I tried procedures mentioned at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash and also at https://boundarydevices.com/readonly-root-filesystem-for-i-mx6-boards-running-debian-or-ubuntu/

It some how mount root with read-only but now I got the problem mentioned at http://askubuntu.com/questions/25695/initramfs-error-during-boot, may be because root filesystem got corrupted.